# How to skip execution without stopping the server in Node Js?

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to skip current execution after some blocks of code executed but the server should not stop, It has to be Up and running on the same port using Node js.

I have tried using `Process.exit()`, `Process.kill()` and `Process.abort()` methods as well. It didn't worked as per my expectations. Those are stopping the server.

Comment: Could you share your code snippet? Are you using Express?

Comment: Yeah i am using express only.

Comment: Maybe you can run it in a child process, and kill it whenever you like. https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html. There is also something like worker threads which might serve your purpose. https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html

Comment: what do you mean by "skip current execution"? How would you determin that you have to "skip current execution" ...